# Javascript: Copying array is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

hi guys could you check why is the array ctrlTable not being returned? I dont have any bugs in the Console.

```
    function setElements() { 
    var tabl = document.querySelector("#table");
    var tabC = tabl.children;
    tabC = [...tabC];
    for (i=0; i<36; i++){
         tabC[i].setAttribute("id", `field${i}`);
         tabC[i].setAttribute("onclick", `fire(${i})`);   
    }   
    return tabC;
    controlTable();
};

function controlTable(tabC){

    var ctrlTable = tabC.slice(0);
     return ctrlTable;  
}

setElements();
```

Comment: You code looks weird to me. Why is that spread operator (`...`) there? Also you're calling `controlTable` with no argument _after_ a return statement.

Comment: You return before you actually call it, so you never come there and no parameters passed. You probably meant `return cantrolTable(tabc);`

Comment: `return` ends a function. Nothing after that will be called.

Comment: @Halcyon I assume it’s to cast it to an array. `.children` returns a live `HTMLCollection` which is not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your

```
  return tabC;
  controlTable();
```

with

```
 return cantrolTable(tabc);
```

As it never reaches the call, if it returns before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
return tabC;
controlTable();
```

with

```
return controlTable(tabC);
```